# Syntax error in UNION ALL

Tags: join, mariadb, union

I have syntax error in UNION ALL line 8.. what is the mistake? I'm using mariadb, (Innodb)

```
SELECT 
'Süre Bitiş Tarihi','Tc Kimlik No', 'Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı','E-posta',
'Telefon','Diğer Telefon','Adres','Şehir','Posta Kodu','Ev Adresi',
'Ev Şehir','Ev Posta Kodu','Barkod', 'Eser Adı', 'Yazar', 'Yeri',
'Kütüphane Adı','Materyal türü','Yerel Yer Numarası','Basım Tarihi',
'Hedef kitle','Dil kodu' 

UNION ALL (

SELECT  
i.date_due, bo.cardnumber,CONCAT(bo.surname,',',bo.firstname),bo.email,
bo.phone, bo.mobile, CONCAT(bo.address,' ',bo.streetnumber,' ',bo.address2),
bo.city, bo.zipcode, CONCAT(bo.B_address,' ',bo.B_streetnumber,' ',bo.B_address2) ,bo.B_city,bo.B_zipcode , it.barcode, 
b.title,b.author,it.location,br.branchname,itype.description,
it.itemcallnumber,b.copyrightdate,bitems.agerestriction,
EXTRACTVALUE(bitems.marcxml,'/record/datafield [\@tag=\"041\"] /subfield [\@code=\"a\"]')

FROM issues i 
LEFT JOIN items it on i.itemnumber=it.itemnumber 
LEFT JOIN biblioitems bitems on bitems.biblioitemnumber=it.biblioitemnumber  
LEFT JOIN biblio b on b.biblionumber=it.biblionumber 
LEFT JOIN itemtypes itype on it.itype=itype.itemtype 
LEFT JOIN borrowers bo on bo.borrowernumber=i.borrowernumber 
LEFT JOIN branches br on br.branchcode=bo.branchcode 
where it.holdingbranch=110 

UNION ALL (

SELECT  
i.date_due, bo.cardnumber,CONCAT(bo.surname,', ',bo.firstname),
bo.email, bo.phone, bo.mobile, CONCAT(bo.address,' ',bo.streetnumber,
' ',bo.address2),bo.city, bo.zipcode, 
CONCAT(bo.B_address,' ',bo.B_streetnumber,' ',bo.B_address2),
bo.B_city,bo.B_zipcode , it.barcode, b.title,b.author,it.location,
br.branchname,itype.description,it.itemcallnumber,b.copyrightdate,
bitems.agerestriction,
EXTRACTVALUE(bitems.marcxml,'/record/datafield [\@tag=\"041\"] /subfield [\@code=\"a\"]') 
FROM old_issues i 
LEFT JOIN items it on i.itemnumber=it.itemnumber 
LEFT JOIN biblioitems bitems on bitems.biblioitemnumber=it.biblioitemnumber  
LEFT JOIN biblio b on b.biblionumber=it.biblionumber 
LEFT JOIN itemtypes itype on it.itype=itype.itemtype 
LEFT JOIN borrowers bo on bo.borrowernumber=i.borrowernumber 
LEFT JOIN branches br on br.branchcode=bo.branchcode 
where it.holdingbranch=110
)
);
```

I don'T want this output

```
ef kitle | Dil kodu |
| Süre Bitiş Tarihi   | Tc Kimlik No | Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı     | E-posta | Telefon | Diğer Telefon  | Adres | Şehir  | Posta Kodu | Ev Adresi | Ev Şehir  | Ev Posta Kodu | Barkod | Eser Adı  | Yazar | Yeri | Kütüphane Adı    | Materyal türü   | Yerel Yer Numarası  | Basım Tarihi  | Hedef kitle | Dil kodu |
| Süre Bitiş Tarihi   | Tc Kimlik No | Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı     | E-posta | Telefon | Diğer Telefon  | Adres | Şehir  | Posta Kodu | Ev Adresi | Ev Şehir  | Ev Posta Kodu | Barkod | Eser Adı  | Yazar | Yeri | Kütüphane Adı    | Materyal türü   | Yerel Yer Numarası  | Basım Tarihi  | Hedef kitle | Dil kodu |
| Süre Bitiş Tarihi   | Tc Kimlik No | Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı     | E-posta | Telefon | Diğer Telefon  | Adres | Şehir  | Posta Kodu | Ev Adresi | Ev Şehir  | Ev Posta Kodu | Barkod | Eser Adı  | Yazar | Yeri | Kütüphane Adı    | Materyal türü   | Yerel Yer Numarası  | Basım Tarihi  | Hedef kitle | Dil kodu |
| Süre Bitiş Tarihi   | Tc Kimlik No | Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı     | E-posta | Telefon | Diğer Telefon  | Adres | Şehir  | Posta Kodu | Ev Adresi | Ev Şehir  | Ev Posta Kodu | Barkod | Eser Adı  | Yazar | Yeri | Kütüphane Adı    | Materyal türü   | Yerel Yer Numarası  | Basım Tarihi  | Hedef kitle | Dil kodu |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
'Süre Bitiş Tarihi','Tc Kimlik No', 'Kullanıcı Soyadı, Adı','E-posta',
'Telefon','Diğer Telefon','Adres','Şehir','Posta Kodu','Ev Adresi',
'Ev Şehir','Ev Posta Kodu','Barkod', 'Eser Adı', 'Yazar', 'Yeri',
'Kütüphane Adı','Materyal türü','Yerel Yer Numarası','Basım Tarihi',
'Hedef kitle','Dil kodu'  
UNION ALL (
SELECT *

from(

SELECT  
i.date_due, bo.cardnumber,CONCAT(bo.surname,',',bo.firstname),bo.email,
bo.phone, bo.mobile, CONCAT(bo.address,' ',bo.streetnumber,' ',bo.address2),
bo.city, bo.zipcode, CONCAT(bo.B_address,' ',bo.B_streetnumber,' ',bo.B_address2) ,bo.B_city,bo.B_zipcode , it.barcode, 
b.title,b.author,it.location,br.branchname,itype.description,
it.itemcallnumber,b.copyrightdate,bitems.agerestriction,
EXTRACTVALUE(bitems.marcxml,'/record/datafield [\@tag=\"041\"] /subfield [\@code=\"a\"]')

FROM issues i 
LEFT JOIN items it on i.itemnumber=it.itemnumber 
LEFT JOIN biblioitems bitems on bitems.biblioitemnumber=it.biblioitemnumber  
LEFT JOIN biblio b on b.biblionumber=it.biblionumber 
LEFT JOIN itemtypes itype on it.itype=itype.itemtype 
LEFT JOIN borrowers bo on bo.borrowernumber=i.borrowernumber 
LEFT JOIN branches br on br.branchcode=bo.branchcode 
where it.holdingbranch=110 

UNION ALL (

SELECT  
i.date_due, bo.cardnumber,CONCAT(bo.surname,', ',bo.firstname),
bo.email, bo.phone, bo.mobile, CONCAT(bo.address,' ',bo.streetnumber,
' ',bo.address2),bo.city, bo.zipcode, 
CONCAT(bo.B_address,' ',bo.B_streetnumber,' ',bo.B_address2),
bo.B_city,bo.B_zipcode , it.barcode, b.title,b.author,it.location,
br.branchname,itype.description,it.itemcallnumber,b.copyrightdate,
bitems.agerestriction,
EXTRACTVALUE(bitems.marcxml,'/record/datafield [\@tag=\"041\"] /subfield [\@code=\"a\"]') 
FROM old_issues i 
LEFT JOIN items it on i.itemnumber=it.itemnumber 
LEFT JOIN biblioitems bitems on bitems.biblioitemnumber=it.biblioitemnumber  
LEFT JOIN biblio b on b.biblionumber=it.biblionumber 
LEFT JOIN itemtypes itype on it.itype=itype.itemtype 
LEFT JOIN borrowers bo on bo.borrowernumber=i.borrowernumber 
LEFT JOIN branches br on br.branchcode=bo.branchcode 
where it.holdingbranch=110
))temp);
```

You are missing from clause in line No 8.  After using Union all you just combine with any temp variable.